# Eventlistener for keydown does not work properly

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I am creating an exercise website that is a drumset and when you either click on a drum or press a corresponding key on the keybord it produces a sound of the corresponding drum. Picture, so that's easier to understand:

[image]

The problem is that the eventlistener for keydown only works after I click on any drum at least once. Here is my js code (I did not put all the cases here, so that's easier to read):

```js
var numberOfDrumButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDrumButtons; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {

        var drumButton = this.innerHTML;
        makeSound(drumButton);
    });
}

for (var j = 0; j < numberOfDrumButtons; j++) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[j].addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {

        var drumButton = event.key;
        makeSound(drumButton);
    });
}

function makeSound(drumButton) {
    console.log(drumButton);

    switch (drumButton) {
        case "w":
            var audio = new Audio("./sounds/crash.mp3");
            audio.play();
            break;

        case "a":
            var audio = new Audio("./sounds/kick-bass.mp3");
            audio.play();
            break;

      default:
          Error("This is not a valid button");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be binding the key listener to the body/document, not the images.

Comment: Also, you should load the audio beforehand so there's no lag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

The problem was that in case of keydown I added the eventListener to the button, not to the document, so that the eventListener only worked when the button was in focus, that's why I had to click it first in order to have it working.

Also, I shouldn't have added the keydown eventlistener numberOfDrumButtons times, since it actually created this time of sounds each time I press the key.

The proper code would be:

```
var numberOfDrumButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDrumButtons; i++) {

  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {

    var drumButton = this.innerHTML;
    makeSound(drumButton);

  });

}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {

  var drumButton = event.key;
  makeSound(drumButton);

});

function makeSound(drumButton) {
  console.log(drumButton);

  switch (drumButton) {
    case "w":
        var audio = new Audio("./sounds/crash.mp3");
        audio.play();
        break;

    case "a":
        var audio = new Audio("./sounds/kick-bass.mp3");
        audio.play();
        break;

    default:
      Error("This is not a valid button");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would re-organize the code and pass the sound name to the function to produce the sound.

- If you click a button, it would grab a data property for the key.
- If you press a key, it would look-up the key in a map to grab the appropriate sound key.

Keep in mind that the key listener should exist at a higher level e.g. the document itself rather than individual keys.

**Edit:** I added audio pre-fetching as D. Pardal noted. I bundled it in the event listener assignment loop.

```js
const sounds = {
  "drum-bass"     : { "key": "a", "filename" : "./sounds/drum-bass.mp3" },
  "drum-snare"    : { "key": "s", "filename" : "./sounds/drum-snare.mp3" },
  "tom-high"      : { "key": "d", "filename" : "./sounds/tom-high.mp3" },
  "tom-mid"       : { "key": "f", "filename" : "./sounds/tom-mid.mp3" },
  "tom-low"       : { "key": "g", "filename" : "./sounds/tom-low.mp3" },
  "cymbal-ride"   : { "key": "h", "filename" : "./sounds/cymbal-ride.mp3" },
  "cymbal-crash"  : { "key": "j", "filename" : "./sounds/cymbal-crash.mp3" },
  "cymbal-hi-hat" : { "key": "k", "filename" : "./sounds/cymbal-hi-hat.mp3" }
}

const keyLookup = Object.entries(sounds).reduce((lookup, entry) =>
  Object.assign(lookup, { [entry[1]['key']] : entry[0] }), {})

const handleClick = (e) => playSound(e.currentTarget.dataset.sound)
const handleKeyPress = (e) => playSound(keyLookup[e.key])

document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress)

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.drum-sound')).forEach(sound => {
  const soundKey = sound.dataset.sound
  const soundData = sounds[soundKey]
  sound.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
  console.log(`Pre-fetching audio: "${soundData.filename}"`)
  sounds[soundKey].audio = new Audio(soundData.filename)
})

const playSound = (soundKey) => {
  const soundData = sounds[soundKey]
  if (soundData) {
    soundData.audio.play()
    console.log(`Now playing: "${soundKey}"`)
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 86px !important; }

.drum-sounds {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: thin solid grey;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.drum-sound {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 3.66em;
  height: 3.66em;
  border: thin solid grey;
  padding: 0.125em;
}

.drum-sound:hover { cursor: pointer; background: #FFA; }

.drum-sound > span { text-align: center; }

.sound-name { z-index: 10; }

.sound-key {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 3.66em;
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.125)
}
```

```html
<div class="drum-sounds">
  <div class="drum-sound" data-sound="drum-bass">
    <span class="sound-name">Bass Drum</span>
    <span class="sound-key">A</span>
  </div>
  <div class="drum-sound" data-sound="drum-snare">
    <span class="sound-name">Snare Drum</span>
    <span class="sound-key">S</span>
  </div>
  <div class="drum-sound" data-sound="tom-high">
    <span class="sound-name">High Tom</span>
    <span class="sound-key">D</span>
  </div>
  <div class="drum-sound" data-sound="tom-mid">
    <span class="sound-name">Mid Tom</span>
    <span class="sound-key">F</span>
  </div>
  <div class="drum-sound" data-sound="tom-low">
    <span class="sound-name">Low Tom</span>
    <span class="sound-key">G</span>
  </div>
  <div class="drum-sound" data-sound="cymbal-ride">
    <span class="sound-name">Ride Cymbal</span>
    <span class="sound-key">H</span>
  </div>
  <div class="drum-sound" data-sound="cymbal-crash">
    <span class="sound-name">Crash Cymbal</span>
    <span class="sound-key">J</span>
  </div>
  <div class="drum-sound" data-sound="cymbal-hi-hat">
    <span class="sound-name">Hi-Hat</span>
    <span class="sound-key">K</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I said, it is just an exercise, and I used the code given in the exercise. Now I have found my mistake and post the solution.